# Issue with Eye Diagram in ADS

Tags: simulation, ads, eye-diagram

I am simulating eye diagram in ADS using the below setup

The schematic is drawn following the ADS manual
[image]

After simulating, I tried to plot the eye diagram using Density
[image]

This is what I get
[image]

but it is quite different to the usual eye diagram below as it supposed to be
[image]

Does anyone know what the issue is?